# Tkinter Entry + Python + Sqlite with params

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am having a lot of problems to understand how to create a tkinter-gui for an sqlite query.

**Idea:**

I have one table with 1.7m+ rows. My queries are divided in three areas: I. queries with 5 variables - II. query with one variable - III. same as II.
(After the output in pandas, I can create and open an xlsx-File, there is no problem.)

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.title('7s_final_004')

        frame = Frame(root)
        frame.pack()

        self.fields = {}


        l = Label(frame, text="Description:")
        l.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.fields['description'] = Entry(frame)
        self.fields['description'].grid(row=1, column=1)`

### self.fields go on for all 5 categories(description2, client, etc...)

        `l = Label(frame, text="Num:")
        l.grid(pady=10, row=19, column=0)
        #self.fields['num'] = Entry(frame)
        #self.fields['num'].grid(row=19, column=1)
        self.numentry = Entry(frame)
        self.numentry.grid(pady=10, row=19, column=1)

## 2/3 buttons plus one exemplary def:
btn_generalsearch = Button(frame, text="Search above", command=self.do_generalsearch)
        btn_generalsearch.grid(row=10, column=0)

        btn_numsearch = Button(frame, text="Search Num", command=self.do_numsearch)
        btn_numsearch.grid(row=20, column=0)

def do_numsearch(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
        #with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        num = """SELECT Client, Ship, Num, Product, Description, Units, Price, Supplier, Cost, 'Date', Margin, DN 
                    FROM table2
                    WHERE Num = ?
                    ORDER BY Date DESC;"""
            #print(num)
        #numargs = self.fields['num'].get()
        numargs = numentry()
        df = pd.read_sql_query(num, conn, param=(numentry))

        print(df.head(5))


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp()
```

**Note:**
I left my messed up do_numsearch as it is, so you might see what I tried already.
I am stuck with this since two weeks.

I would like to add a radiobutton-widget and checkboxes too, I would be very glad if someone could point me in a direction how I can make this piece work.

Comment: I can't understand what the question is?

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry. I have not been able to make a query in tkinter work, especially for the query with 5 variables. I get various mistakes, fix one, create another. 
How can I fix my code (to transfer it to the rest), declare the variables to be able to use them with the sql query?